# I can't change the value of a serialized variable in Unity's custom inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just learned how to (partially) use unity's custom inspector. I mainly want to use this to serialize specific variables if a bool or enum or whatever is true.
Anyway, in a test project I made a bool called usesSpeed. Then I made a float called speed. But I only want to serialize speed whenever usesSpeed is true. That works well, however the problem is I can't change the value of speed through the inspector at all. I can't "drag" the value or input anything. It's always just 0.
Here's my code.

```
public class script : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public float speed;
    public bool usesSpeed;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(speed);
    }
    [CustomEditor(typeof(script))]
    public class edtr : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            script scrpt = (script)target;
            base.OnInspectorGUI();
        if (scrpt.usesSpeed)
        {
              
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Speed stuff");
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("speed"));
                
        }
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **1)** Custom Editors written in C# should be placed in a child folder named **Editor**.  i.e. **Editor/edtr.cs**.  Normal and editor scripts appear in **Assembly-CSharp.csproj** and **Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj** respectively.  The reason being is that Editor scripts are treated differently at editor-time (naturally) **_and_** they are not compiled into the final game.  **2)** Additionally Unity doesn't like multiple class definitions in the same file, sometimes only the first `MonoBehaviour` is detected. https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/SpecialFolders.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was just add this at the end and everything works great.

```
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```